# Loosing my primaryKey during Query({Importhtml1; Importhtml2;...}) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I need to query up to 50 Sources with dynamic length. Thats why it has to be an all in one command.

The Length of each Source is changing very often. Each Source has RowA as Primarykey. But after the query over all sources, the key isnt unique anymore.

Let´s say my Sources look like this:

```
SourceA      SourceB      SourceC 
James  5     Jack  3      Jane  5
Steve  3     James 1      Steve 1
```

Then this Code:

```
=Query({Importhtml("ScrA";"table";1); Importhtml("ScrB";"table";1); ...})
```

returns this:
Result:

```
James 5
Steve 3
Jack  3
James 1
Jane  4
Steve 1
```

As u can see, i don´t know from which Source "Steve" is coming - but i need to know...

Is there any way to get a result like this (Remember that all Sources have changing Lengths)?

```
ScrA  James  5
ScrA  Steve  3
ScrB  Jack   3
ScrB  James  1
ScrC  Jane   4
ScrC  Steve  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 {REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("ScrA"; "table"; 1);;1)&""; ".+"; )&"ScrA"\
                     IMPORTHTML("ScrA"; "table"; 1)}; 
 {REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("ScrB"; "table"; 1);;1)&""; ".+"; )&"ScrB"\
                     IMPORTHTML("ScrB"; "table"; 1)}}; 
 "where Col2 is not null"; 0))
```

Comment: Sir, that´s great! Thank you! I´ll have a look at regexreplace - completely new to me. :)